# When using Twitter-bootstrap how to prevent grid's 3rd column to to move down when resizing a window?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

Whenever I resize the window, the 3rd column jumps down. 
How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

[my code](http://bootply.com/99941)

Thank you!
Keren.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `col-xs-6`, which takes up half the screen on low-width screen sizes. If you change it to `col-xs-4`, it should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Grid system works the same on each size. Seperated into 12 parts